# VHDL bidirectional testbench-UUT module

Tags: vhdl

I am a bit new to the VHDL world and need some guidance on something that may seem trivial to many.

That I want is to build a bidirectional Testbench-UUT module,where I would be able to control the inputs’ flow given by the testbench, from my main module.

Actually,I need to say to my testbench when I am ready to process the new input.

Something like, raising a flag from my ‘main’ module that would enable the testbench to push a new input in.That  could possibly be controlled by an if statement, and if that flag is ‘up’ allow the next input to flow in.

I am fiddling around with inout ports,but haven’t managed sort it out this way...

Could you please assist me, and if possible give some short example code?

G

Answer (score 1):

One fairly straightforward way of doing this is to use `wait until` in your stimulus process in your testbench.  If you have a data ready signal output from the block you're testing, it just look like:

```
STIMULUS_PROCESS: process
    while (not loopCondition) loop
        -- Apply stimulus to the inputs
        wait until dataReady = '1';
        -- Read the outputs and repeat.
    end loop;
end process;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply!I am afraid that this is what am trying to do...but if there is no sensitivity list to trigger the process for different events  ,that 'loopCondition' you are referring doesn't stand since the loopCondition argument "doesn't come in" roughly  speaking.

Comment: In simulation, a process with no sensitivity list "runs continuously."  If there is no sensitivity list, you must have a wait statement in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,i had to include a sensitivity list in my testbench process,that would contain any flag would be useful for triggering the next input.
G